# Newly created Spring boot starter project throws ClassNotFoundException on startup

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I created a new spring boot project using Spring Tools 3 add on in Eclipse. When I am trying to run the basic application, it is throwing a ClassNotFoundExcecption.

I am trying to use this Application as a Spring Cloud Config Server. Initially it showed ClassNotFoundException for TextEncyptor class also then I added spring-security support which resolved it. But with this I am unable to figure out which dependency i am missing. I tried adding support for web, actuator but nothing worked. Is it a versioning issue? If so, how can I resolve it? Moreover this is an auto-generated project.

```
Here's my pom.xml:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
            http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
           <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
           <parent>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
                <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
            </parent>
            <groupId>com.microservices</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <name>spring-cloud-config-server</name>
            <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

        <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
            <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RC2</spring-cloud.version>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>spring-milestones</id>
                <name>Spring Milestones</name>
                <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </project>
```

Here's the StackTrace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationPropertiesImportSelector$ConfigurationPropertiesBeanRegistrar.lambda$collectClasses$1(EnableConfigurationPropertiesImportSelector.java:83) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.LinkedList$LLSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationPropertiesImportSelector$ConfigurationPropertiesBeanRegistrar.collectClasses(EnableConfigurationPropertiesImportSelector.java:85) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationPropertiesImportSelector$ConfigurationPropertiesBeanRegistrar.getTypes(EnableConfigurationPropertiesImportSelector.java:78) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationPropertiesImportSelector$ConfigurationPropertiesBeanRegistrar.registerBeanDefinitions(EnableConfigurationPropertiesImportSelector.java:70) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.lambda$loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars$1(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:364) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:145) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:327) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:691) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:528) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
at com.microservices.springcloudconfigserver.SpringCloudConfigServerApplication.main(SpringCloudConfigServerApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
```

Main class:

```
  import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
  import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

  @SpringBootApplication
    public class SpringCloudConfigServerApplication {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(SpringCloudConfigServerApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to rebuild the project?

Comment: Yes, I did. I tried rebuilding, updating, cleaning the project. But nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on other similar questions - it might be a maven cache issue. I would recommend to clear .m2 folder and try to build again.

See similar issue here:
https://github.com/spring-io/initializr/issues/457

Another but without feedback:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12466

I was able to run the project locally with your pom.xml and your main class and basic configuration in application.yml.

Another recommendation - try to exclude IDE possible problems, try to run you project using

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I cleared the .m2 folder and tried again. that helped. Thank you.

Comment: or rather, rename .m2 to keep a backup of any local artifacts, if you had added those before

Comment: +1 for suggesting to exclude IDE misconfiguration - in my case Compile On Save setting in Netbeans was messing up my Java build